# Handle arrays in react-native withouth listview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm quite new to `react-native` and I've managed to get a list of items with their detail page but I haven't found any solution on how I can load an array of strings on the detailpage without using a `listview`

I have an array of image URLs, how can I display these? Maybe I'm missing the point and I'm too much focused on `ng-repeat` in `Angular`

What I want to see:

```
<View>
 <Text>{item.title}</Text>
 <Text>{item.description}</Text>
 <Image></Image> //image 1
 <Image></Image> //image 2
 <Image></Image> //image 3
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the images and store them in a variable, then use the variable in your return statement:

```
const images = arrayOfImages.map((image, i) => {
    return <Image
             key={i}
             source={{uri: image}}
             style={styles.image} />
})
```

Then use the array like this:

```
<View>{images}</View>
```

I set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/f6A5NQ) for more context.

https://rnplay.org/apps/f6A5NQ

Comment: is there any benefit to use const or inline code?
<View>{images.map(i => <Image ... /> )}</View>

Comment: @heat No benefit, just whichever your preference is really.